# How to establish an association in Rails between two models with the same column name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, pg

I have a problem, usually I run a migration and add a column called employee_id to Attendace model, then establish the relation and its done, but for company's rules I cannot change the db. So to connect a model with other I must work with a column with same name and both models, But I can't accomplish the relation. I leave the code.

```
class Attendace < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :employee, :class_name => "Employee", :foreign_key => "private_number"
end

class Employee < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :attendaces, :class_name => "Attendace", :foreign_key => "private_number"
end
```

The common column for both models is a field called "private_number" which is a string.

The error that arises is when I try to get the employee and their attendances is:

```
2.7.2: 001> Employee.joins (: attendaces)
Traceback (most recent call last):
ActiveRecord :: StatementInvalid (PG :: UndefinedFunction: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = bigint)
LINE 1: ... OIN "attendaces" ON "attendaces". "Private_number" = "Empleo ...
                                                         ^
HINT: No operator matches the name and type of the arguments. It may be necessary to add explicit type casts.
```

The tables

```
create_table "attendaces", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string "private_number"
 t.date "date"
 t.time "time"
 t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
end

create_table "employees", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string "email"
 t.string "name"
 t.string "lastname"
 t.string "position"
 t.string "private_number"
 t.boolean "active"
 t.bigint "company_id", null: false
 t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
 t.index ["company_id"], name: "index_employees_on_company_id"
end
```

Comment: Could you share your migration file @Adrian Rama?

Comment: I share to schema with the db's tables. Taking into consideration that I can't make changes to schema.

Comment: The column wich is common for both is "private_number".
A join between attendances and employees on attendances.private_number =  employees.private_number.

Comment: Thx for the response and for share your schema @Adrian Rama, but what I want to check is the migration generated in order to add the foreign key properly, it doesn't look like you added that foreign key

Comment: Are you sure you posted the actual code? in the Error there is clearly a space between "attendaces" and "Private_number". Also the fact that "Private_number" is lead by an uppercase "P" seems to suggest that the doe posted does not match what is in your code base.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I think you need to do, based on the info you shared:
Even when you added the `:foreign_key` directive within your model, you need to generate a new migration in order to apply those changes at the DB level, after add that foreign key at the DB level, your schema should have also a new index. With that said here is how you can do it:

`rails g migration <name_of_your_migration>`, this command will generate a file where you can add the foreign key to the DB by adding this line to the change method: `add_foreign_key :attendaces, :employees, column: :private_number`.

Here are the docs for [add_foreign_key](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_foreign_key).
Hope this helps!